# installing CppUnit Libraries and CppUnit Includes

Tags: c++, cppunit

I'm trying to compile a software from source codes. In one compiling stage, I need to navigate the directory which holds CppUnit Libraries (e.g. /home/user/lib) and CppUnit Includes (e.g. /home/user/include). How can I install these CppUnits and navigate them into ubuntu 14.04?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

```
sudo apt-get install libcppunit-dev
```

This command installs library and headers.

Comment: I've done it. When I run apt-cache policy libcppunit-dev; I got Installed: 1.13.1-2ubuntu1
  Candidate: 1.13.1-2ubuntu1
but when I run locate libcppunit, I got nothing. How can I navigate CppUnit Libraries and CppUnit Includes?

Comment: [here](http://packages.ubuntu.com/trusty/amd64/libcppunit-dev/filelist) you can find the list of files installed by the package.